# Curious distribution

Tags: distributions

While checking my Android App Rating I saw this

[image]

It's almost a quadratic progression!
Is there any explanation for such a rating?

Comment: Explanation: there is more people who like your app then those who don't. While you have pretty small number of ratings the actual numbers could be pure coincidence.

Comment: Zipf's Law. But the underlying mechanism that produces proportional frequencies is not well understood. Also your sample size is pretty small.

Comment: Perhaps "exponential" (base two) is intended rather than "quadratic" (which would suggest 2 in the index)?

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is that a lot of people like the app and not many don't like it. You have a limited range (1 to 5) and a small sample.

Suppose the range wasn't 1 to 5 (which don't have labels here but might translate in one's head into something like "Not very good" for 1 to "very good" for 5, although it's hard to tell) but 1 to 100 with descriptions for 1 = "the worst piece of software I have used in my life" and 100 being "absolutely fantastic, essential, necessary, WOW". Then suppose that, on this scale, your app's rating is normally distributed with mean = 80 and sd = 10. That would probably come close to the distribution you got on the 1 to 5 scale.